# What yield of nuclear explosive would need to be detonated in Valencia, Spain, to flood the Balearic Islands?

Tags: geography, natural-disasters, nuclear-weapons, topography

A nuclear device goes off on the beach in [Valencia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valencia), Spain - immediately adjacent to the ocean. How large will this device need to be in order to flood a majority of the human settlements in the [Balearic Islands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balearic_Islands) via tsunami?

My current reference is the [Lituya Bay](http://geology.com/records/biggest-tsunami.shtml) tsunami, in which 30.6 million cubic meters of rock plunged 914 meters into Lituya Bay, producing a wave more than half a kilometer high.

Assuming drag is negligible, falling 914 meters means an end velocity of 126.35 meters per second.

Assuming that the rock in question had a density of ~2.65 grams per cubic centimeter, that means that 81.09 megatons of rock hit the water.

That's a kinetic energy release of 0.1547020688 megatons, a far cry from the [largest single detonation humanity has ever caused](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsar_Bomba). This is the only reason that I think that flooding the Balearics with a nuclear device is even possible; there's more than two orders of magnitude to go here.

Alternatively, if a nuclear device were detonated mid-way between the Balearics and Valencia, what yield would it need to be to cause significant/lethal flooding?

Comment: Rule of thumb - the "total destruction" blast radius will be greater than the tsunami radius for any ground burst.  For a location 300 km away, this will be enormous - gigatons at a guess.  If you want flooding without total destruction of the entire island down to the bedrock then you need a deep underwater detonation much closer to the islands.

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 Thank you for the response; I'll pose a new question. If a bomb were to detonate mid-way between the Balearics and Valencia, how powerful would it need to be to cause significant flooding?

Comment: As per previous comment, it needs to be deep underwater, and it will still need to be enormous.  Unless flooding the islands and the Valencia beach while sterilising and/or contaminating a lot of the water in between is the purpose, not sure why anyone would detonate a device of the required size there.

Comment: ? The rocks falling into the ocean caused a tsunami because there were a lot of rocks, adding up to a very large volume, and when they fell into the ocean they displaced an equally *very large volume of water*. The speed of the fall was almost irrelevant. Water is incompressible, so that the displaced water had to go somewhere: and that somewhere being a Very Large Wave. I don't really see how to duplicate the effect using an explosion. Sure, a large explosion will produce a moderately impressive wave, but that wave will be reduced to a ripple at a distance of hundreds of kilometers.

Comment: To clarify @AlexP'a answer, the issue is more that, at Litiuya Bay, the water was highly constrained. All of it had to go pretty much one place, over the opposite headland and narrow channel, hence the huge wave headline height. Your explosion could move that exact same volume of water, but in the open seas theres nothing constraining it, so it can spread out, and the spread scales as distance squared (area of a circle). Also youre considering the effects at hundreds of km to spread over, not <1km. That, combined, why you only get a much smaller wave as AlexP says.

Comment: @Stilez: The difference between a massive rock fall and and an explosion is that with the rock fall the displaced water stays displaced and *must* go elsewhere. With an explosion, the water is displaced initially but then the bubble collapses and the water returns, leaving no water to go carousing abroad in the form of a tsunami.

Comment: Suppose such a wave *could* be caused by a medium size asteroid impact halfway Valencia and the Balearic islands.. but that would be off topic as answer.

Comment: @AlexP, i think thats incorrect. Momentum and wave physics. It doesnt matter if the bubble collapses, or disspates at the surface. Its already set in motion the wave and provided a few million tons of water (or whatever it may be) with momentum. Conservation of momentum means that water isnt going to suddenly stop. The water adjacent to or above the bubble will collapse into the space once the bubble dissipates, but none of that will undo any of the outward momentum of water already in motion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two aren't comparable. Lituya was a highly constrained channel, and under 1km distance. The Balearic isles are about 320km and open seas.

We can get an "order of magnitude" idea of scale like this.

Valencia to Mallorca, about 320 km. [This altitude map](https://en-gb.topographic-map.com/maps/lsz7/Balearic-Islands/) zoomed a bit, combined with Google Maps for settlement locations, suggests about 250m, at most 300m, to flood a majority of human settlements. So you need a wave that is **still 250m high** at 320km distance.

Thats immensely more massive than Lituya. Or as [one article](https://www.livescience.com/52370-mega-tsunami-swallowed-ancient-island.html) puts it, considering a huge prehistoric megatsunami, the Fogo flank collapse that flooded the Cape Verde islands, about 70,000 years ago......

> [S]cientists were uncertain how much damage tsunamis that are triggered by volcanic collapses might cause in the open seas. All the giant waves triggered by volcanic collapses in the past few hundred years occurred in confined spaces that concentrate the energy of such collapses into smaller volumes of water. In contrast, in the open ocean, previous research suggested that waves generated by landslides generally lose energy quickly.
>
> Now scientists have found evidence that a sudden volcano collapse triggered a giant tsunami dwarfing anything in recorded history that traveled dozens of miles.

Note the scale - at "dozens" of miles distance. And thats from a historical fall that dwarfs Lituya. The linked article contains the data. **38 cubic miles**, over 5000 times as much volume as Lituya ( which was 30million cubic m, or 0.0072 cubic miles). And even so, in open seas, the wave was only about 170m (estimated) when it reached Santiago, 34 miles away. You want a wave that is still over 50% higher, by the time it travels almost 6 times further (200 miles = 320km).

Lets estimate. Assume the wave height scales roughly as wave length (wave keeps same shape profile?) then 1.5x higher means order of magnitude 2x cross section area (1.5^2 = 2.25, round down to avoid over estimating). 6x further away = 6x circumference of circle, but you might be able to halve this because Valencia is only half surrounded by water not fully. So say 3x. So total volume of water to move is 2 x 3 = 6x the Fogo volcanic collapse, or about 230 cubic miles....

**And that's why your explosion is never going to do the job. You'd have to collapse well over 200 cubic miles of rock and soil from the Spanish coastline into the Mediterranean (or displace that much water abruptly by some other means), to stand a chance.**

(Your underwater version halfway between is not much help.  Even at half the distance, you'd still need to displace about <s>a hundred</s> 200 cubic miles of water. *(Half the distance so half the circumference but open seas not coastal so you don't get the halving from it being a coastal wave, this wave has to be 360 degrees not 180 degrees; the two alterations virtually cancel out)*. Just not going to happen. Not even slightly close. Not even a small fraction of one cubic mile....)

Answer (score 2):

**[Operation Crossroads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Crossroads) has some indications**

In June and July of 1946 the United States decided to see what atomic weapons would do to naval vessels.  So they took a fleet of captured / surplus ships to the Bikini Atoll and attacked them with atomic weapons.  I mean, who wouldn't.

Able, used on June 30, was an airburst that missed its mark somewhat and contributes nothing to the tsunami narrative.  Baker, used on July 24, was an entirely different beast.  A 23 kT atomic bomb detonated 27 metres underwater, it destroyed numerous vessels.  More importantly for the purpose of this question, it started a tsunami - not by pushing water out, but by vapourising a huge bubble of water, leaving an empty space that other water rushed in to fill.  At about 300 metres from surface zero the first wave was 29 metres high.

However, by the time it reached the beach 6 km away, it was a series of breakers only 5 metres high.  (The detonation also resulted in an environmental disaster and long term health issues for lots of people, but let's focus on the wave action.)

Now, it's hard to extrapolate directly from the shallow waters of the Bikini Atoll to deep waters off Spain, but let's pretend they are comparable.  Working from Stilez excellent answer, let's say the waves need to be 300 m high rather than 5 m high when they reach the beach.  The water won't just arbitrarily shape itself into a high wave with no (front-to-back) depth, so we need to ramp up the destructive force not by 60 but by its square - ie 3600 times more powerful.  But we also need the waves to achieve this effect at a distance of 300 km rather than 6 km.  The exact multiplication here is unclear:

- the force of the detonation will be going in all directions (suggesting distance squared)
- but there will be reflection from the Earth's crust beneath the detonation (suggesting 1/2 d squared)
- yet the tsunami frontage is a circle rather than a sphere (suggesting distance alone)

Taking the middle option of 1/2 multiplied by the square of the increase in distance gives 0.5 * 50 * 50 or an increase by a factor of 1250 in required yield.

Putting all that together:  Detonating a nuclear weapon with a yield of 23 kT * 3600 * 1250 = 103,500,000 kT (103.5 gigatons) at an ideal depth in the water in the vicinity of Valencia, Spain, *might* be enough to flood the Balearic Islands.  However, that would probably be the least of the consequences.  Note that this is approximately 2000 times more powerful than the highest yield nuclear weapon ever created and tested ([Tsar Bomba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsar_Bomba)).

Comment: One complicating factor is that its not at all clear that volume displaced/vapourised/bubbled/collapsed, scaled linearly with explosive megatonnage. I have a memory that it doesnt, that the effect of a 10 MT warhead is not 10x that of a 1 MT warhead, but much more modest.  Thats one reason I worked in volume not warhead size

Comment: @Stilez I can easily believe that it doesn't scale linearly - for example, it's possible that for a bigger bomb a much bigger proportion of the energy simply takes the path of least resistance and blasts up through the atmosphere.  So I upvoted your answer but tried to work out a possible required yield anyway.  If someone was serious about flooding the islands then they would probably need a series of much smaller devices deployed in some kind of pattern, but that's outside the question's scope and the amount of time I'm willing to spend on it.

Comment: Fair comments and approach :)

Answer (score 0):

If some madman wants to flood the Balearic Islands, they should explode their bomb or bombs somewhere within the Balearic Islands.

They should find a very wide and very tall underground cliff, presumably on the shores of Mallorca,  and drill several long horizontal tunnels into the side of the cliff, and place their atomic bombs inside with timers, and and let the bombs vaporize many cubic kiometers and cubic miles of rock, which should explode out into the water and cause giant tsunamies.

And if they create vast hollows in the cliffs, the cliffs might collapse in giant landslides, starting a second set of giant tsunamies.

And they might have to plant their bombs in several different locations if they want to inundate all of the Balearics instead of only one or two islands.  And they should be careful to sell all their Mediterranean beachfront property before setting off the bombs, since the tsunamies wil strike with lesser force all over the Mediterranean like the 2004 Indian Ocean tsunami.

And possibly someone may be able to calculate the bomb yield necassary for this revised plan to work.